# displaying to records using Access 2010 sql

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

i've created a table called cust. has the columns, customer_number address and balance. customer numbers range from 100-105. what i am trying to do is get the balance of customer numbers 102 and 104.this is what i have tried and shows no results.  customer 102 has a balance of 300, and 104 has a balance of 1900. here is what i tried:

```
select customer_number, balance
from Cust
Where customer_number = '102' and customer_number = '104';
```

but when i look at the output, i do not see those two records showing up. i know its something to do with my where clause, but i cannot seem to figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `and` to `or`. Using `and` would mean you're looking for a record that has both the customer_number 102 AND the customer_number 104, which doesn't really make sense...